# UWP - Unselectable NavigationViewItem but Clickable

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

What I would like to create is a NavigationViewItem which is not selectable but is clickable. For example the "New Message" item in UWP App Mail that you see in the image.

[image]

When clicked the item show a dialog window but the selection does not change and the colored bar does not move from the previous selected item.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<NavigationViewItem SelectsOnInvoked="False"/>
```

It's a new dependency property in Windows 10.1809.  See the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.selectsoninvoked#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationViewItem_SelectsOnInvoked).